# Is this equality based on the HDM true?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model

It is stated in [Sterile Neutrinos as Dark Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9303287) that in the HDM model: $$\frac{\mu^2}{m_s}= 92 h^2 \text{eV} \tag{1}$$
where $m_s$ represents the mass of sterile neutrinos and $\mu^2$ represents the Dirac mass.

I'm also told that: $$\frac{m_\nu}{\Omega_\nu} \approx 92 h^2 \text{eV} \tag{2}$$

this is based on the HDM model and is an approximation of the formula for the mass of all neutrinos in a system (I can't find the source of this formula).

**My question:**

Does this mean that $(1)=(2)$, $\frac{\mu^2}{m_s}=\frac{m_\nu}{\Omega_\nu}$ at all times?

What I mean by this is, if I use a type 1 see-saw Lagrangian, which gives me the equation: $$ \frac{\mu^2}{m_s} = \sin^2 \theta m_s \tag{3}$$

**Could I instead rewrite equation $(2)$ as follows?** $$\frac{m_\nu}{\Omega_\nu}= \sin^2 \theta m_s$$

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.